# Android Studio: How to scroll in the preview window?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a ScrollView in my app and now I would like to scroll to the bottom of he screen in the  Android Studio preview-window, but I don't really know how to do that. Is that possible, or is there an option to switch to a "fullscreen" mode?

Answer (score 0):

I might be totally wrong here but I have never seen that someone did that. The basic reason must be that there is no way to tell how many entries the ListView might have.